# PHP i need year format like 2015-16

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to store year like *2014-15* in **MySQL**. when i use this code means it will store -1; so plz help me out.. for Financial Year calculation.

```
$date=strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));  
$fdate=strtotime(date('Y-03-31'));    
if($date <= $fdate) 
{
    $facyear=(date('Y')-1)-(date('Y')); 
}
 else if($date > $fdate) 
{
    $facyear=(date('Y'))-(date('Y')+1); 
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO fyear (id, facyear) VALUES ('', '$facyear')");
```

Comment: By 2014-15 means you want to store only Year and Month in this format in database and not day ? You should store yyyy-mm-dd and you can retrive year / month /date separately for calculation as per requirement.

Comment: no. thats short for 2014-2015

Comment: Why not just concatenate it like `date('Y').'-'.(date('Y')+1)`?

Comment: please check this. http://rakeshrsingh.com/blog/details/id/21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to create your string using numerical operators.

Try:

```
$facyear=(date('Y')-1) .'-'. date('y');
```

and

```
$facyear=date('Y') .'-'. (date('y')+1);
```

That way it concatenates them rather than subtracting them.

That is the error you are making in your PHP code.  I don't know how your fields are set up in your database, so I can't say for certain if it will still insert it correctly - but at least your string data would be correct.